# Converting string to active record query statement

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

inside one of my view pages I'm using old fashion way of presenting data but I have problem in converting a string like "User.country.name" to a query statement. 
I'm using a loop like below :

```
@columns = ['id','email','name','country.name']

table = User.all

<% table.each do |row| %>
    <% @columns.each do |field| %>
         <%= row[field] %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The table shows almost all data except for column "country.name". I can't use constantize for country.name it gives me error. Any solution ? Thanks

Comment: if I write row[field].constantize it shows : NoMethodError in Table#show_table , undefined method `constantize'. Without constantize it shows the id, email and name fields of each row except last one with empty field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `User` doesn't have an attribute `country.name`, it has an *association* `country` and that association has an attribute `name`.

You could set up a [delegate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate):

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   delegate :name, to: :country, prefix: true
   # ...
 end
```

This creates a method `User#country_name`, returning `country.name`.

Now you can adapt your loop, using [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send) to call the methods: (I've changed the variable names to make it clearer)

```
@methods = [:id, :email, :name, :country_name]

records = User.all

<% records.each do |record| %>
  <% @methods.each do |method| %>
    <%= record.public_send(method) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@users = User.select(:id, :email).joins(:countries)

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.id %>
  <%= user.email %>
  <%= user.countries %>
<% end %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins

Wish it helps